# assertEquals problems (object object) (long long)

Tags: java, junit

```
Interval<Integer> interval1 = Intervals.open(3, 6);
```

Here `3` is the lower bound, and `6` is the upper bound.

```
assertEquals(interval1.lowerBound(), 3);
```

After writing the test, there is a red underline saying:

```
ambiguous method call.Both assertEquals(object, object) assertEquals(long, long)
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you're calling `assertEquals` with a `Long` and an `int`, so the compiler can't tell whether you want `assertEquals(long, long)` (autounboxing the `Long`) or `assertEquals(Object, Object)` (autoboxing the `int`).

To fix this, you need to handle the unboxing or boxing yourself, by writing either this:

```
assertEquals(3L, interval1.lowerBound().longValue());
```

or this:

```
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(3L), interval1.lowerBound());
```

(Incidentally, note that I swapped the order of the two arguments for you. `assertEquals` expects the first argument to be the expected value and the second to be the actual value. This doesn't affect the assertion itself, but it affects the exception-message that's generated when the assertion fails.)

Comment: the first way stay the same, but second way could fix the red underline. but it pumps out : java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.Integer<3> but was: java.lang.Long<3>